# How to make a difference between two Time.now.utc.iso8601?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, datetime, iso8601

I have :

last_transition_date = Time.now.utc.iso8601()

......

x = Time.now.utc.iso8601() - last_transition_date

but it gives error :

'undefined method `-' for "2012-05-28T10:50:13Z":String'

Solutions?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to minus a string from another string. Strings do not have a `-` method.

Comment: I know, but there are two dates, is there a way to make a difference, for example with a type cast or a particular function?

Comment: @SimoneMazzotta Is there a `to_i` available anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You should make just

```
last_transition_date = Time.now.utc
x = Time.now.utc - last_transition_date
```

Then you will take float result

Comment: now it works, but I have the same problem as before, the difference between two timestamp is expressed in microseconds, as I can turn it in seconds or milliseconds? for example => x = 2.000.000 ( 2 sec )